# how to update and then insert a record with unique key constraint

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, upsert

i have a table with columns a,b,c and c having the unique key constraint.

```
a |b |c(uk)
----------
aa 1  z
```

I want to insert a new row with values (bb,1,z), if z already exists then i first want to update the existing row to

```
a |b |c(uk)
----------
aa 1  null
```

and then insert (bb,1,z), so that the final rows looks as shown below.

```
a |b |c(uk)
----------
aa 1  null
bb 1  z
```

how can i do this a single sql statement?

Comment: Note: UNIQUE+nullable is an ugly combination. What is the intended Primary Key for this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately unique constraints are checked per row in Postgres - unless they are created as "deferrable".

So if you want to do the UPDATE and the INSERT in a single statement, you will have to re-create your unique constraint with the attribute deferrable. Then Postgres will check it at the end of the *statement*.

```
create table the_table 
(
  a text, 
  b int, 
  c text
);

alter table the_table 
    add constraint unique_c 
    unique(c)
    deferrable --<< this is the "magic"
;
```

Then you can do it with a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
with input (a,b,c) as (
  values ('bb', 1, 'z')
), change_old as (
  update the_table
  set c = null
  from input
  where input.c = the_table.c
)  
insert into the_table
select a,b,c
from input;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) for this.

In the trigger you would update all the records containing value new.c like:

```
UPDATE my_table SET
  c = NULL
WHERE 
  c = new.c;
```

If c is not present - nothing will happen.

You may still run into unique constraint violation error if 2 concurent transactions inserts  the same value into c. To avoid that you can use [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) providing lock ID from value of c.

Comment: since i am new to advisory locks , i have tried out 
making the unique key constraint to deferrable and it worked. Thanks for this approach, and i would like to try to this.